# GIT - error open () - error: unable to index file

Tags: git, git-add

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Utilizo git como control de versiones y cuando hago `git status` aparece un archivo que no he creado. Ya hice lo que encontré en stackOverflow en ingles, cerré y abrí el Visual Studio varias veces y reinicie la computadora, pero el supuesto archivo llamado `kipping...` (asi en seco) sigue estando.

`git status` me muestra lo siguiente:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        kipping...
```

y `git add .` me dice esto:

```
error: open("kipping..."): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file 'kipping...'
fatal: adding files failed
```

¿Que puedo hacer? Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Lo ves también en el navegador de archivos de tu sistema, o si haces `ls -l`?

Comment: no, no lo veía, tuve que guardar los archivos que hice y las modificaciones aparte. Elimine todos los archivos del trabajo e hice un pull del repositorio original que estaba en github. Cuando elimine Todos los archivos, me apareció el cartel que no podía eliminar ese, le puse omitir y siguió con el resto.. al final de todo quedo a la vista ese archivo "kipping..."

Comment: ¿No será algo del IDE o algo como dropbox o  google drive que esté usando también esos directorios?

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar una extensión del archivo válido, por ejemplo .txt, .csv, etc.
Renombrar el archivo, por ejemplo `kipping....csv`

despues:
`git add .`